# ViewCell not align correctly and cut part of content - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView in Xamarin Forms XAML, in this ListView I want to draw a Grid with 4 labels and 1 Entry. My problem is that, when I try to display the ListView, its rows are superimposed and not all the content of the ViewCell, into the DataTemplate, is displayed.

I don't know what is my error.

Here my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="iGuideTest.ExhibitionsPage"
    Title = "{Binding titleMenu}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="You are in the Exhibitions page" />
            <Button Text="Return to LoginPage" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
            <Label Text="{Binding exhibitionsList.Count}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding surname}" Command="{Binding Edit}" />
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewCouchbase" ItemsSource="{Binding exhibitionsList}"
                >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="#05199C" Text="{Binding title}" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="#008000" Text="{Binding userId}" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Maroon" Text="{Binding LastUpdated}" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Purple" Text="{Binding surname}" />
                                <Entry Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Blue" Text="{Binding Id}" />
                                </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing a `RowHeight` for your the list.

Comment: I have already set RowDefinition Height="Auto"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to use [`HasUnevenRows`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HasUnevenRows/) property:

`<ListView HasUnevenRows="True">
      ... 
  </ListView`>

Comment: All of my rows are the same size but label text was still being cut off. So I'm not sure why, but HasUnEvenRows="True" is the right answer.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `RowHeight` affects how `HasUnevenRows` works: "Third, and finally, if the developer sets RowHeight to a positive value, then all rows in the ListView will, irrespective of the height of their content, be as tall as RowHeight, as if HasUnevenRows had been set to false."

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `Grid` and you have `Auto` in `RowHeight` you will be better of setting `HasUnevenRows` property to true.

Also your grid is of dynamic size on its own, you can set its `VerticalOptions` to `Fill`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i've been there :)

just set ListView RowHeight="xx" where xx is some double indicating the height.